# WAMP server name not found for virtual host in apache

Tags: apache, dns, localhost, wamp, virtualhost

System: Windows7 64-bit
WAMP server 32-bit version: Apache : 2.4.9 MySQL : 5.6.17 PHP : 5.5.12 PHPMyAdmin : 4.1.14 SqlBuddy : 1.3.3 XDebug : 2.2.5

My issue is that when I navigate to my project "local.blamo1.com" - via WAMP "Localhost" chrome returns: "Oops! Google Chrome could not find local.blamo1.com"

I am able to access my project folder with "localhost/local.blamo1.com" - But as I understand it, this is bad practice as it will throw off server mapping by one directory. I would like to be able to access the project with the designated server alias. I have implemented the following...

httpd-vhosts.conf
Location: "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\extra\httpd-vhosts.config"

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at 
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www"
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAlias localhost
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www">
        AllowOverride All
            Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/local.blamo1.com"
    ServerName local.blamo1.com
    ServerAlias local.blamo1.com
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/local.blamo1.com">
        AllowOverride All
            Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

hosts file
Location: "C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts"

```
# Copyright (c) 1993-2009 Microsoft Corp.
#
# This is a sample HOSTS file used by Microsoft TCP/IP for Windows.
#
# This file contains the mappings of IP addresses to host names. Each
# entry should be kept on an individual line. The IP address should
# be placed in the first column followed by the corresponding host name.
# The IP address and the host name should be separated by at least one
# space.
#
# Additionally, comments (such as these) may be inserted on individual
# lines or following the machine name denoted by a '#' symbol.
#
# For example:
#
#      102.54.94.97     rhino.acme.com          # source server
#       38.25.63.10     x.acme.com              # x client host

# localhost name resolution is handled within DNS itself.
#   127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1 localhost
127.0.0.1 local.blamo1.com

#::1 localhost
#::1 local.blamo1.com
```

httpd.conf
Location: "C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.4.9\conf\httpd.conf

***I have un-commented these lines***

```
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so
```

Current Diagnosis

Apache httpd -t return: "Syntax OK"

I think this has something to do with my DNS or ports, or whatev - as I do not have enough experience with this level or how the DNS is not able to resolve the domain:

after I tried to ping the project:

ping local.blamo1.com
"Ping request could not find host local.blamo.com. Please check the name and try again.

Please help me understand why I am getting this issue. I have been working on this for a day and a half. Apologies if there is not adequate information for your to make a diagnosis of the problem. I will provide more information as necessary.

All my best.

Answer (score 5):

I was able to solve this issue - props to this post: http://www.tweaksforgeeks.com/windows7/2011/02/windows-7-hosts-file-ignored

The issue appeared to be a corrupted "hosts" files - all I know for sure was that the solution was to delete the hosts file and create a new one with raw text from the old. The causality is inexplicable.

Comment: I installed Apache service in WAMP 3.1.9 64bit and my htaccess was corrupted (all was in one line). Editing this was enough. Thank you!

Comment: the link is not found (404)

Answer (score 0):

This solve my problem. After hours of making it work. Turns out I was careless about the host file. Saving as txt and then just removing the extension to replace the original file.